# Two total orders

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Let $\mathcal{R}$  and $\mathcal{S}$ be two total orders on $E$ such that $\forall(x,y) \in E\times{E}, x\mathcal{R}y \Rightarrow x\mathcal{S}y$. Show that $\forall(x,y) \in E\times{E}, x\mathcal{R}y\Leftrightarrow x\mathcal{S}y$.

I need some help with this problem. I know that a total order is a set where every pair of elements in a relation such that anti-symmetry and transitivity holds. However I am having a problem from transferring from a relation $\mathcal{R}$ to a relation $\mathcal{S}$. Could you please give me some hints?

Comment: Try to use contradiction. That is given $xSy$ assume that $yRx$.

Comment: Anti-simmetry and transitivity are the characteristics of *orders*. A *total* order must satisfy [totality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) as well. And that's the point here, because you may want to prove that $\neg(x\mathcal R y)\Rightarrow \neg(x\mathcal S y)$.

Answer (score 1):

We are going to use the converse of

$$x\mathcal Ry \Rightarrow x\mathcal S y$$

which is

$$\neg (x\mathcal Ry) \Rightarrow \neg(x\mathcal S y).$$

The order is total, so if we have $\neg (x\mathcal Ry)$ we have $y\mathcal R x$.

By the first property it gives us

$$y\mathcal S x.$$

By anti-symetry we can conclude that $x=y$ or $\neg (x\mathcal Sy)$.

But $x=y$ can not be because $\neg(x\mathcal Ry)$ (and you always have $x\mathcal R x$).

So $\neg (x\mathcal Sy)$.

Finally,

$$x\mathcal Ry \iff x\mathcal S y.$$

Comment: This isn’t quite right. Once you have $y\mathrel{\mathcal{S}}x$, antisymmetry tells you that either $x=y$, or $\neg(x\mathrel{\mathcal{S}}y)$. The initial assumption that $\neg(x\mathrel{\mathcal{R}}y)$ implies that $x\ne y$, and after you point that out, you can conclude the argument exactly as you did.

Comment: You're right @BrianM.Scott, thanks, I edited.

Comment: Looks fine now; +1.